# Writing to a specific already running process instead of creating a new instance of a process

Tags: c++, c, windows, stdin

I have written some code that calls an executable and passes arguments to it via the cmd line.

For example it will call

```
my_process.exe -A my_argument
```

What I want to happen is that my program `my_process` will always be running looking for user input and instead of creating a new instance of the process I am wanting to write my data/arguments to the existing process.

I understand that how I am passing the parameters will change from the the initial process start (argc, argv) vs when using stdin.

I also know that I will have to change how I am calling the process but I am unsure of what I need to look into to get this done.

**EDIT**: so what I am trying to accomplish by doing all of this is below:

```
Website >> Web Service API >> Hardware API >> PLC
```

The website is on server A, the web Service and Hardware API is on Server B

OS is Windows 10 Pro 64bit

PLC is a programmable logic controller

The website will send a post to my webservice. The webservice will call the Hardware API which in turn will write or read data to the PLC.

This works when doing a single POST. But when doing multiple POSTS if the connection from the Hardware API to the PLC is still open it will fault.

The Connection between the Hardware API and the PLC is like a COM port not like a socket (which is misleading based on the programming manual).

So what I was trying to do was to keep my Web API the same but create another process that will take all the results from the Web API and put them in a FIFO and then pop them off to the Hardware API (which I will always have running and will have a persistent connection to the plc).

So really the Hardware API would always be running and be a single process that gets data passed to it. The Queue service would always be running and the Web API would pass the results over to it.

I have looked into the below:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/interprocess.html

child/parent process/fork/file descriptors/dup/dup2

Any thoughts or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How to solve thing like this is *very* operating-system dependent. What operating-system are you programming for?

Comment: Window 10 Professional. Sorry should have included that in the original post.

Comment: The [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) functions allows you to set file streams to be used for standard input and output. Using pipes you could pass the read-end to the new process, and when you write to the pipe the process can read it from its standard input.

Comment: But doesn't the createprocess fucntion only create a new instance of the process?
Once the process is created how do I write data over to it?

Comment: It sound like what you need is for my_process to be listening on a network socket and for other processes to connect it.

Comment: I have thought of trying to do that actually. It was going to be a last resort. If that's the best way thats fine. I'll edit the original post and detail what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: On Windows, you could try to use COM/DCOM. Delightedly non portable, but you get a full Windows integration

Comment: When you call `CreateProcess` you pass a pointer to a [`STARTUPINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa) structure. This structure contains members that are file handles. These file handles will be used for standard input, output and error inside the new process (and the program it runs). There are plenty of tutorials on how to use *pipes* to "communicate" with a program started by `CreateProcess`.

Comment: So after looking through the CreateProcess and looking over pipes I was able to come up with a way to create an instance of my process and get data from stdin and pipe it back to the prompt. What I haven't figured out yet is how to pipe it to the input of the actual program. Still looking through tutorials but everything is dealing with parent/child processes. Is this necessary in order for me to get this to work?